# Binomial trees in binomial heap with 27 elements

Tags: data-structures

How many binomial trees are in a binomial heap with 27 elements and how would you find this number?

Comment: It would improve the question to replace $27$ with $n$, so that it is more general. You could also describe more context: where this problem comes from, why you are interested in it, and a link to or copy of the definition of a binomial heap.

Answer (score 2):

A binomial heap stores a collection of binomial trees whose sizes are powers of two and such that there is at most one tree for each size.

How can you write 27 as a sum of distinct powers of 2? How many powers do you need?

Comment: $2^0+2^1+2^3+2^4=27$ So there are 4 binomial trees, am I right?

Comment: Yes.$\phantom{}$